# CSS -> border-bottom not showing 1.5px

Tags: html, css

I want to show border 1.5px, I can't able to see. It's showing same as 1px. I don't want 2 px, bcz it's much broad for me

```css
.newTitle {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<p class="newTitle">stack Overflow</p>
```

Comment: Well, as long as your monitor can't illuminate *half* a pixel, I think you might be out of luck there...

Comment: Try a double border instead of a solid one? It really depends on the color. 2px light grey won't look as weird as 2px red for example.

Comment: (To be fair, 1px in CSS doesn't necessarily equal 1 physical pixel, but often enough, this is actually the case)

Comment: [This](http://atirip.com/2013/09/22/yes-we-can-do-fraction-of-a-pixel/) article shows a neat trick to fake the half pixel, which browsers mostly just ignore.

Comment: you'll have to find a compromise since pixels cannot be broken in pieces , a shadow might give the illusion to thicken it a bit : 
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px  -1px orange  demo : https://jsfiddle.net/phugj8d2/

Answer (score 9):

comment turned into answer:

you'll have to find a compromise since pixels cannot be broken in pieces , a shadow might give the illusion to thicken it a bit :

`box-shadow: 0 1px 1px -1px orange`

demo

```css
.newTitle {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid orange;
}

.bis {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px -1px orange
}

.ter {
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<p class="newTitle">stack Overflow  (1px)</p>
<p class="newTitle bis">stack Overflow (1px + shadow)</p>
<p class="newTitle ter">stack Overflow (2px)</p>
```

Comment: This probably comes closest to what OP wants. It looks quite believable to me on my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the definition of a pixel this doesnt surprise me.
Maybe an added shadow feels better than the 2 px border to you.

Comment: Good idea! Too bad you didn't include an example. Now someone else did.

Answer (score -2):

You can try it in EM.
Assuming that EM is 16px, 1.5px = 0.09375em
Good luck!

Comment: And then his screen still has to show that as *either one or two* rows of red pixely pixels.

Comment: Not working @mariante